# Delete command is working but showing a blank page after button click

Tags: c#

I have a add product function. After adding the product, I have a link that will view all the added products in a GridView. Well this 2 functions are working perfectly fine. In the view products page, I have there a edit and delete function. Both are working fine but when I try to click on the delete and click on OK, it shows me a blank page ( but when I try to get back to the page, the product is deleted) any ideas what I am missing here?

this is the code for the viewproducts page:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ProductID" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="ProductDescription" />
        <asp:ImageField HeaderText ="ProductImage" DataImageUrlField="ProductImage" SortExpression="ProductImage" ControlStyle-Width ="10">

            <ControlStyle Width="50px"></ControlStyle>

            </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductQuantity" HeaderText="ProductQuantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" HeaderText="ProductPrice" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        <%--<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" 
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm Delete?');"></asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication5

{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=Authorship;Integrated Security =True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                gvbind();
            }
        }
        protected void gvbind()
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int prodid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ProductID"].ToString());
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=Authorship;Integrated Security =True");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
            conn.Open();
            da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from Products where ProductID=" + prodid, conn);
            da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gvbind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");
        //TextBox txtname=(TextBox)gr.cell[].control[];
        TextBox textName = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        TextBox textDesc = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
        TextBox textQuantity = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
        TextBox textProductPrice = (TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
        //TextBox textadd = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtadd");
        //TextBox textc = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtc");
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        conn.Open();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM detail", conn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Products set ProductName='" + textName.Text + "',ProductDescription='" + textDesc.Text + "',ProductQuantity='" + textQuantity.Text + "',ProductPrice ='" + textProductPrice.Text + "'where ProductID='" + userid + "'", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        gvbind();
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvbind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        gvbind();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebind datasource gaing back to gridview , so in you code it will be like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int prodid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ProductID"].ToString());
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=Authorship;Integrated Security =True");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
            conn.Open();
            da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from Products where ProductID=" + prodid, conn);
            da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            //GridView1.DataBind();
           gvbind();
        }
```

So as per above code you need to call `gvbind();` method which binds datagrid again rather than calling method `GridView1.DataBind();`.

Comment: it works fine on other products. but when i delete the last product, it is still there. but when i refresh it, its gone.

Comment: ive done it. iva added the gvbind(); and also retain the GridView1.DataBind(); thank you!